# Local mongodb Node.js server succesfully authenticates then ends connections after a few seconds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, local

I am trying to run an Express server that would communicate with a local MongoDB instance. Everything runs on Ubuntu 18.04.5 on DigitalOcean.

I managed to set up the database, the authentication is made, but then after a few seconds the connection closes due to some mongodb dependencies (I think).

This is how I make the connection:

```
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

const mongooseConnection = mongoose
                          .createConnection(
                            `mongodb://user:pass@127.0.0.1:27017/Database?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
                            { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
                          );

mongooseConnection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection error: '));

mongooseConnection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("Connected to the DB");
  httpsServer.listen(securePort, () => {
    console.log(`Secure Express server listening on port ${securePort}`);
  });
});
```

**Node console:**

[image: This is the result:]

**Mongod:**

[image]

Couldn't find much about this error. Most of what I've found is related to the MongoDB Atlas cloud service, but this is a local MongoDB instance. The common solution for when the connection closes like this seems to be whitelisting the IP. I think this is not the case as everything is local and I have nothing to do with the Atlas/Cluster.

I tried removing the node modules and updating them. I tried disabling **cors** and **helmet**. I'm stuck

Comment: You've redacted the IP address from the node exception, but the mongod log shows the IP of the connection as 127.0.0.1, is that not the same as the error message?

Comment: I connect to 127.0.0.1 as the code shows, but the error outputs the actual IP. I also opened the port, because I thought it might access it from the outside somehow (idk why it would do that tho'), but it still doesn't work